# get audio current freqency for each 0.1 second of audio file with ffmpeg sox or opus into file.txt

Tags: php, ffmpeg, frequency, sox, frequency-analysis

I am trying to get audio freqency statistic from call record in file.opus for each 0,1 second, have try ffmpeg (spectrum) ffprobe , 
for example
`sox  '.$file.' −n rate 6k spectrogram −z 62 -w Hamming -o aaaaaa/test10.png stat -freq 2>aaaaaa/test10.txt`
return spectrum
all of them return values but no freqency found any other library ? Or what I am doing wrong I now it retrun spectrum but I need concrete freqency of human voice it is possible with ffmpeg or ffprobe or sox ? I am working in php but running shel comands any help will be aprisiatied. What should be my next step? I am lost I have no idea how could get freqency from this numbers or "it is possible " ??? What is the first step comand in sox etc.

Comment: I have not found documantation to get freqency of voice and I am new in ffmpeg and sox

Answer (score 0):

So , I am have I think "not nice" solution, for beginner in audio good article witch help me [FFT for beginner](http://www.vlf.it/fft_beginners/fft_beginners.html) then study documentation for [SOX stats](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html%20stat) use following code to get

1. Rough Freqency

```
$z = 0;
$timeFrom = 0;
$freqencies = array();
$fftPoints = 4098/2; 
//sox could give only 2048 freqencies spectrum
$file = 'myMp3Test.mp3';// 10 seconds
$interval = 1/8;//1/8 second 
//best results I got with this interval smaller gives as well zeros
//80 because 10 seconds interval 1/8 = 80 measurments
while($z <= 80){

    $outputexec = '';   

    exec('sox  '.$file.' −n trim '.$timeFrom.' '.$interval.' rate 1024 stat -freq  2>&1', $outputexec);

    $timeFrom = $timeFrom + $interval;

    $resultLength = (count($outputexec)-12) ;
  // - 12 means extra 12 rows in result with stats
    $cycles = $resultLength / $fftPoints ;

  $x = 1;
    while($x<=$cycles){

        $buffer = array();
        $till = $fftPoints*$x;

        $i = $till - $fftPoints;

        while($i < $till){
            $prA = explode("  ",$outputexec[$i]);
            if(isset($prA[1])){ $buffer[] = $prA[1]; }
            $i = $i + 1;
        }   

        $maxValue = max($buffer);

        $j = ($till>$fftPoints)? $till - $fftPoints: 0;

        while($j < $till){
            $prB = explode("  ",$outputexec[$j]);
            if(isset($prB[1])){
                if($prB[1] == $maxValue) { 
                     $freqencies[] = $prB[0];
                    break;
                }
            }           
            $j = $j + 1;
        }

        $x = $x + 1;
    }
    $z = $z+1;
}

//result is in freqencies arrray
```

2. Mean volume

```
exec('ffmpeg -i "'.$file.'" -filter:a volumedetect  -f null /dev/null 2>&1', $outputrmsA );
foreach($outputrmsA as $vysledok){
    if(preg_match("/mean_volume/", $vysledok)){
        $vprenos = explode('mean_volume: ',$vysledok);
        $mean_volume = (trim(str_replace(" ", "",(str_replace(" dB", "",$vprenos[1])))));
    }
}
var_dump($mean_volume);
```

3. Spectrum,png
   `exec('sox  '.$file.' −n rate 4096 spectrogram −z 60 -w Hamming -o aaaaaa/ORG.png');`

I am kindly open for corrrections or better answers, thx for any advice
I had test it on my personal mp3 and it was with 0,005 tolerance OK

Comment: Looking for better resolution of freqencies 4098 and less time interval then 1/8